# How to view number of objects created by class or program in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, object

How to view the number of objects created by a c sharp class or application is there any feature in Microsoft Visual studio 2013??

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2012, you can right click on the project, and choose "Calculate Code Metrics". This should probably also be there in 2013? If so, it will give you some insight.

Comment: Re-Reading your post, I may have misinterpreted?